# Clearcase config spec time rules

Tags: timestamp, config, clearcase, rule, config-spec

I try to understand how reliable are the time rules of ClearCase 8.0.1.4 when used in config spec.
So, when I specify a time in config spec, will it be taken before **not** including the specified time stamp? or will it take the before and including specified time stamp?

For example if I have the rule:

```
element * .../main/LATEST -time 26-Mar-2014.13:03:53UTC+01:00
```

and versions:

```
version 1 has time stamp of 26-Mar-2014.13:02:10UTC+01:00

version 2 has time stamp of 26-Mar-2014.13:03:53UTC+01:00
```

Which one will be chosen?

Can I rely that it will be always consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but, according the [config spec man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-6-2):

```
-time date-time
```

> Modifies the meaning of the special version label LATEST: the rule selects from a branch the last version that was created **before a particular time**.

So it should be version 1

The creation times of the versions on the branch are looked up in their create version event records.

Note that it can vary depending on ClearCase: With Multisite, the selection can change depending on the package synchronized "[Time rules in config specs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_config_spec_time_rules.htm)")

Comment: Hi VonC, 
this is true, however, most of the time it also works "before including the time", in other words, version 2 is chosen.
That's why I can't understand what should I rely on? if I always add 1 second to the time stamp, will I pick up the needed version or any other rule of thumb should  be used?

Comment: @DeadStar yes, to be "on the safe side", adding one second should work. But only IBM support would be able to have a definitive answer here.

Comment: @VobC, I guess you are right, being on the save side helps. Not sure if even IBM can promise consistency in such situation. From my personal experience, it is inconsistent, and both options could be chosen with the given cs